# Sharepoint rest api get shortcuturl

Tags: api, rest, sharepoint

I am able to connect to the Sharepoint REST api, all good, I am missing one important property, which I think is present, but probably hidden somewhere.
I am fetching details of an item like this

```
https://myco.sharepoint.com/teams/Intranet/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Site Pages')/items?$orderby=Modified desc&$top=11&$select=Title,Id,Description,BannerImageUrl,Properties/vti_x005f_shortcuturl&$expand=Properties
```

What I've read is that `Properties/vti_x005f_shortcuturl` should give me the result, however; this object is empty in my response:

```
{
"Properties": {},
"Id": 1567,
"Title": "This is awesome",
"BannerImageUrl": {
    "Description": "https://myco.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/getpreview.ashx?path=%2Fteams%2FIntranet%2FSiteAssets%2FSitePages%2F98z8hx4c%2F1426231370-nuno-dash.jpg&ow=1920&oh=1080",
    "Url": "https://myco.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/getpreview.ashx?path=%2Fteams%2FIntranet%2FSiteAssets%2FSitePages%2F98z8hx4c%2F1426231370-nuno-dash.jpg&ow=1920&oh=1080"
 },
 "Description": "December 3 is International Day of Persons with Disabilities (IDPD)",
 "ID": 1567
 }
 //omitted rest of results
```

I would like to have a `url: 'https://gotothewebversion'` so when displaying the result somebody can click on the link and go to the article.

EDIT:
On 1 particular item the `Properties` is filled, but there is no shortcutUrl.

Somebody has a clue how to achieve this?

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to retrieve a URL link to the file by expanding "File" in the REST query and then selecting File/ServerRelativeUrl.

```
$expand=File&$select=*, File/Name, File/ServerRelativeUrl
```

Comment: Thank you ouflak for applying the code font.