# Get the preview URL in SharePoint Document library via REST API

Tags: sharepoint, fetch-api, sharepoint-rest-api

I am making a custom web part that connects to the Documents list on SharePoint via Fetch. This is the call that I use for retrieving information:

/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Documents')/items?$select=EncodedAbsUrl,*,File/Name&$expand=Folder&$expand=File

Right now I get mostly all the data that I need for all the items, but I just need to also have the URL that redirects you to the preview of the file
[Example of file preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hvoww.jpg)

If possible, I don't want to make another fetch, So **is there any item property that I could expand to get the preview URL, via REST API?**

I checked the values of EncodedAbsUrl and ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl, but these are not exactly the preview URL that I have in mind.

I've seen a similar question to mine, even tho I don't need the same thing I've also tried expanding the fetch to recieve more data of vti_x005f but still, I couldn't find the preview URL

[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59978719/get-the-url-behind-link-items-in-sharepoint-document-library-via-rest-api)

With this one:
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Documents')/items?$select=EncodedAbsUrl,*,File/Name/Properties/vti_x005f_shortcuturl&$expand=Folder&$expand=File&$expand=Properties

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?$select=*,FileLeafRef,FileRef
```

then use for pdf or word

```
absoluteUrl + "/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=" + FileRef + "&file=" +FileLeafRef + "&action=default"
```

for images

```
/sites/Development/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?id=/sites/Development/Shared Documents/lehladakh.jpg&parent=/sites/Development/Shared Documents
```